# Is it more pythonic to manipulate object I/O with @property vs override __getitem__?

Tags: python, inheritance, dictionary, properties

Given say a dictionary of data (could come from a database entry), what is the more correct way to wrap that dictionary's data in an encapsulating class that has control over what the data can be set to and is returned as?

Specifically, the two ways I have in mind to do this is to:

1. Override a `dict` inherited class' `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods
2. Within a standard `object` inherited class, add a `@property` decorator for each data entry that needs to be controlled.

For example:

```
class SmartContainer(dict):

    ## Format/check items as they are returned
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        if key == "birthday":
            return "Happy Birthday!{bdate}".format(bdate=self.get('birthday'))
        if key not in self.keys():
            return 0

    def __init__(self,baseDict):
        super(SmartContainer,self).__init__(baseDict)

class SmartContainer2(object):
    @property
    def birthday(self):
        return "Happy Birthday! {bdate}".format(bdate=self._birthday)
    @birthday.setter
    def birthday(self,value):
        self._birthday = value

    def __init__(self, baseDict):
        [self.__setattr__(k,v) for k,v in baseDict.iteritems()]
```

In this purely arbitrary example, I have two classes that implement each architecture.

```
smartContainer=SmartContainer({"pi":3.14, "birthday":"01/01/2016"})
smartContainer['birthday'] 
>>>'Happy Birthday! 01/01/2016'

smartContainer2=SmartContainer2({"pi":3.14, "birthday":"01/01/2016"})
smartContainer2.birthday 
>>>'Happy Birthday! 01/01/2016'
```

Both methods work, and it seems to me like the `@property` decorator is more widely used for such actions. But the dynamic nature of the `SmartContainer` class' access abilities seem more straightforward to me. AKA `smartContainer[dynamic_key]` vs `smartContainer2.__getattr__(dynamic_key)`.

I am wondering if there is a reason to use one method over the other, and what potential pitfalls exist?

Comment: Your description _"Given say a dictionary of data"_ and your example of a class with a known variable `_birthday` are very different! If you want to wrap a `dict` of arbitrary content, `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` are a good way to go... with the restriction that the contained keys follow python attribute syntax (e.g., can't have a key called "your birthday"). Writing functions to get/set the contained dict is also reasonable to remove that restriction.

Comment: By that I just mean that you are to construct an object that wraps access to a given dataset, the contents of which are at least partially known ahead of time. Database entry, some tuple, dictionary, dataframe, etc. You know what is coming in, and would like to control access after instantiation.